# Remove surrounding whitespace from an image

Tags: c#, vb.net, graphics

I have a block of product images we received from a customer.  Each product image is a picture of something and it was taken with a white background.  I would like to crop all the surrounding parts of the image but leave only the product in the middle.  Is this possible?

As an example: [http://www.5dnet.de/media/catalog/product/d/r/dress_shoes_5.jpg][1]

I don't want all white pixels removed, however I do want the image cropped so that the top-most row of pixels contains one non-white pixel, the left-most vertical row of pixels contains one non-white pixel, bottom-most horizontal row of pixels contains one non-white pixel, etc.

Code in C# or VB.net would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've written code to do this myself - it's not too difficult to get the basics going.

Essentially, you need to scan pixel rows/columns to check for non-white pixels and isolate the bounds of the product image, then create a new bitmap with just that region.

Note that while the `Bitmap.GetPixel()` method works, it's relatively slow. If processing time is important, you'll need to use `Bitmap.LockBits()` to lock the bitmap in memory, and then some simple pointer use inside an `unsafe { }` block to access the pixels directly.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11.aspx?fid=3488&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=76&select=1123224) on CodeProject gives some more details that you'll probably find useful.

Comment: Does this take too much time to process for a 1000x1000 Image? Please advice.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "too much time" - which is dependent on your context. I'd suggest writing the code using `Bitmap.GetPixel()` and then benchmarking the result to see. Also note that a smart algorithm is more important than micro-optimization of individual pixel reads.

Answer (score 50):

I found I had to adjust Dmitri's answer to ensure it works with images that don't actually need cropping (either horizontally, vertically or both)...

```
    public static Bitmap Crop(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        int w = bmp.Width;
        int h = bmp.Height;

        Func<int, bool> allWhiteRow = row =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
                if (bmp.GetPixel(i, row).R != 255)
                    return false;
            return true;
        };

        Func<int, bool> allWhiteColumn = col =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
                if (bmp.GetPixel(col, i).R != 255)
                    return false;
            return true;
        };

        int topmost = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < h; ++row)
        {
            if (allWhiteRow(row))
                topmost = row;
            else break;
        }

        int bottommost = 0;
        for (int row = h - 1; row >= 0; --row)
        {
            if (allWhiteRow(row))
                bottommost = row;
            else break;
        }

        int leftmost = 0, rightmost = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < w; ++col)
        {
            if (allWhiteColumn(col))
                leftmost = col;
            else
                break;
        }

        for (int col = w - 1; col >= 0; --col)
        {
            if (allWhiteColumn(col))
                rightmost = col;
            else
                break;
        }

        if (rightmost == 0) rightmost = w; // As reached left
        if (bottommost == 0) bottommost = h; // As reached top.

        int croppedWidth = rightmost - leftmost;
        int croppedHeight = bottommost - topmost;

        if (croppedWidth == 0) // No border on left or right
        {
            leftmost = 0;
            croppedWidth = w;
        }

        if (croppedHeight == 0) // No border on top or bottom
        {
            topmost = 0;
            croppedHeight = h;
        }

        try
        {
            var target = new Bitmap(croppedWidth, croppedHeight);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
            {
                g.DrawImage(bmp,
                  new RectangleF(0, 0, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
                  new RectangleF(leftmost, topmost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
                  GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            return target;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(
              string.Format("Values are topmost={0} btm={1} left={2} right={3} croppedWidth={4} croppedHeight={5}", topmost, bottommost, leftmost, rightmost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
              ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For PNG files with the 'transparent whitespace' I have added checking for bmp.GetPixel(i, row).A != 0 and bmp.GetPixel(col, i).A != 0 (alpha level of zero). Now my PNGs are working great. Thank you for the code! Note: I run bmp.GetPixel() once then analyze R and A properties to prevent double scan.

Comment: I will add an extra case that need to be treated: I have a small image and I will use a `FillRectangle(Brushes.White,...)` -> then my image will have not only 255 so you should better correct it. Values for white: `W:0 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:1 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:2 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:3 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:4 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:5 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:6 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:7 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:8 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:9 H:0 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:0 H:1 a:255 b:254 g:254 r:254
W:1 H:1 a:255 b:255 g:255 r:255`

Comment: This solution has several off-by-one errors that lead to a 1-pixel white border on the left and top.  Another user [posted a fixed version below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001569/238419)

Comment: I posted this many years ago, I would encourage people to try this slightly modified one, if it works for you bump it up this comment and I'll update this answer to be the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001569/329367

Answer (score 18):

Here's my (rather lengthy) solution:

```
public Bitmap Crop(Bitmap bmp)
{
  int w = bmp.Width, h = bmp.Height;

  Func<int, bool> allWhiteRow = row =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
      if (bmp.GetPixel(i, row).R != 255)
        return false;
    return true;
  };

  Func<int, bool> allWhiteColumn = col =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
      if (bmp.GetPixel(col, i).R != 255)
        return false;
    return true;
  };

  int topmost = 0;
  for (int row = 0; row < h; ++row)
  {
    if (allWhiteRow(row))
      topmost = row;
    else break;
  }

  int bottommost = 0;
  for (int row = h - 1; row >= 0; --row)
  {
    if (allWhiteRow(row))
      bottommost = row;
    else break;
  }

  int leftmost = 0, rightmost = 0;
  for (int col = 0; col < w; ++col)
  {
    if (allWhiteColumn(col))
      leftmost = col;
    else
      break;
  }

  for (int col = w-1; col >= 0; --col)
  {
    if (allWhiteColumn(col))
      rightmost = col;
    else
      break;
  }

  int croppedWidth = rightmost - leftmost;
  int croppedHeight = bottommost - topmost;
  try
  {
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(croppedWidth, croppedHeight);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
    {
      g.DrawImage(bmp,
        new RectangleF(0, 0, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
        new RectangleF(leftmost, topmost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return target;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(
      string.Format("Values are topmost={0} btm={1} left={2} right={3}", topmost, bottommost, leftmost, rightmost),
      ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: works perfectly except when the croppedWidth or croppedHeight is zero, in this case I set them to the bmp.Width or bmp.Height respectively, and it works like a charm :)

Comment: does this work for every image? like png jpeg or gif?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG yes, it should, they all get read into a Bitmap that provides by-pixel addressing. please note that this solution isn't very fast and there are much faster ways of doing this (outside of .NET)

Answer (score 10):

I needed a solution that worked on large images (GetPixel is slow), so I wrote the extension method below. It seems to work well in my limited testing. The drawback is that "Allow Unsafe Code" has to be checked in your project.

```
public static Image AutoCrop(this Bitmap bmp)
{
    if (Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bmp.PixelFormat) != 32)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Autocrop currently only supports 32 bits per pixel images.");

    // Initialize variables
    var cropColor = Color.White;

    var bottom = 0;
    var left = bmp.Width; // Set the left crop point to the width so that the logic below will set the left value to the first non crop color pixel it comes across.
    var right = 0;
    var top = bmp.Height; // Set the top crop point to the height so that the logic below will set the top value to the first non crop color pixel it comes across.

    var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    unsafe
    {
        var dataPtr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;

        for (var y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                var rgbPtr = dataPtr + (x * 4);

                var b = rgbPtr[0];
                var g = rgbPtr[1];
                var r = rgbPtr[2];
                var a = rgbPtr[3];

                // If any of the pixel RGBA values don't match and the crop color is not transparent, or if the crop color is transparent and the pixel A value is not transparent
                if ((cropColor.A > 0 && (b != cropColor.B || g != cropColor.G || r != cropColor.R || a != cropColor.A)) || (cropColor.A == 0 && a != 0))
                {
                    if (x < left)
                        left = x;

                    if (x >= right)
                        right = x + 1;

                    if (y < top)
                        top = y;

                    if (y >= bottom)
                        bottom = y + 1;
                }
            }

            dataPtr += bmpData.Stride;
        }
    }

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    if (left < right && top < bottom)
        return bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(left, top, right - left, bottom - top), bmp.PixelFormat);

    return null; // Entire image should be cropped, so just return null
}
```

Comment: If you're looking to just trim transparency, modify the "if ((cropColor.A > 0...) {" line above to simply "if (a != 0) {".  Then you can get rid of the cropColor variable, as well.  Works great so far.

Comment: what do you mean by Allow Unsafe Code

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG You can fine more information on the unsafe flag and how to turn it on for your project in Visual Studio at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0.aspx. It basically allows you to use pointers in a traditional sense with arithmetic and such.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for on a quick-turnaround project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

fix remaining 1px white space at the top and left

```
    public Bitmap Crop(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        int w = bitmap.Width;
        int h = bitmap.Height;

        Func<int, bool> IsAllWhiteRow = row =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                if (bitmap.GetPixel(i, row).R != 255)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };

        Func<int, bool> IsAllWhiteColumn = col =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
            {
                if (bitmap.GetPixel(col, i).R != 255)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };

        int leftMost = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < w; col++)
        {
            if (IsAllWhiteColumn(col)) leftMost = col + 1;
            else break;
        }

        int rightMost = w - 1;
        for (int col = rightMost; col > 0; col--)
        {
            if (IsAllWhiteColumn(col)) rightMost = col - 1;
            else break;
        }

        int topMost = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < h; row++)
        {
            if (IsAllWhiteRow(row)) topMost = row + 1;
            else break;
        }

        int bottomMost = h - 1;
        for (int row = bottomMost; row > 0; row--)
        {
            if (IsAllWhiteRow(row)) bottomMost = row - 1;
            else break;
        }

        if (rightMost == 0 && bottomMost == 0 && leftMost == w && topMost == h)
        {
            return bitmap;
        }

        int croppedWidth = rightMost - leftMost + 1;
        int croppedHeight = bottomMost - topMost + 1;

        try
        {
            Bitmap target = new Bitmap(croppedWidth, croppedHeight);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
            {
                g.DrawImage(bitmap,
                    new RectangleF(0, 0, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
                    new RectangleF(leftMost, topMost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            return target;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Values are top={0} bottom={1} left={2} right={3}", topMost, bottomMost, leftMost, rightMost), ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly possible. In pseudocode:

```
topmost = 0
for row from 0 to numRows:
    if allWhiteRow(row): 
        topmost = row
    else:
        # found first non-white row from top
        break

botmost = 0
for row from numRows-1 to 0:
    if allWhiteRow(row): 
        botmost = row
    else:
        # found first non-white row from bottom
        break
```

And similarly for left and right.

The code for `allWhiteRow` would involve looking at the pixels in that row and making sure they're all *close* to 255,255,255.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void TrimImage() {
    int threshhold = 250;


    int topOffset = 0;
    int bottomOffset = 0;
    int leftOffset = 0;
    int rightOffset = 0;
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@"e:\Temp\Trim_Blank_Image.png");


    bool foundColor = false;
    // Get left bounds to crop
    for (int x = 1; x < img.Width && foundColor == false; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < img.Height && foundColor == false; y++)
        {
            Color color = img.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (color.R < threshhold || color.G < threshhold || color.B < threshhold)
                foundColor = true;
        }
        leftOffset += 1;
    }


    foundColor = false;
    // Get top bounds to crop
    for (int y = 1; y < img.Height && foundColor == false; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < img.Width && foundColor == false; x++)
        {
            Color color = img.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (color.R < threshhold || color.G < threshhold || color.B < threshhold)
                foundColor = true;
        }
        topOffset += 1;
    }


    foundColor = false;
    // Get right bounds to crop
    for (int x = img.Width - 1; x >= 1 && foundColor == false; x--)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < img.Height && foundColor == false; y++)
        {
            Color color = img.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (color.R < threshhold || color.G < threshhold || color.B < threshhold)
                foundColor = true;
        }
        rightOffset += 1;
    }


    foundColor = false;
    // Get bottom bounds to crop
    for (int y = img.Height - 1; y >= 1 && foundColor == false; y--)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < img.Width && foundColor == false; x++)
        {
            Color color = img.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (color.R < threshhold || color.G < threshhold || color.B < threshhold)
                foundColor = true;
        }
        bottomOffset += 1;
    }


    // Create a new image set to the size of the original minus the white space
    //Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(img.Width - leftOffset - rightOffset, img.Height - topOffset - bottomOffset);

    Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(img);
    croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(
                    new Rectangle(leftOffset - 3, topOffset - 3, img.Width - leftOffset - rightOffset + 6, img.Height - topOffset - bottomOffset + 6),
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);


    // Get a graphics object for the new bitmap, and draw the original bitmap onto it, offsetting it do remove the whitespace
    //Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBitmap);
    //g.DrawImage(img, 1 - leftOffset, 1 - rightOffset);
    croppedBitmap.Save(@"e:\Temp\Trim_Blank_Image-crop.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

I have got code from other post in ms, but that has **bugs**, I have **changed something**, now it works good.

*The post from http://msm2020-sc.blogspot.com/2013/07/c-crop-white-space-from-around-image.html*

Answer (score 1):

The `pnmcrop` utility from the `netpbm` graphics utilities library does exactly that.

I suggest looking at their code, available from http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: FWIW imagemagick's `convert -trim` also does exactly that :)

Answer (score 0):

@Jonesie works great, but you have a bug with AllWhiteColumn
pixel was wrong calculated  `var px = i * w + col;` is correct.
Also isTransparent should include white color SKColors.White or better compare it using rgb with offset r,g,b >200

Answer (score -1):

I copied to a version that works with SkiaSharp.

```
using SkiaSharp;
using System;

//
// Based on the original stackoverflow post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248141/remove-surrounding-whitespace-from-an-image
//
namespace BlahBlah
{

  public static class BitmapExtensions
  {
    public static SKBitmap TrimWhitespace(this SKBitmap bmp)
    {
      int w = bmp.Width;
      int h = bmp.Height;
      
      // get all the pixels here - this can take a while so dont want it in the loops below
      // maybe theres a more efficient way?  loading all the pixels could be greedy
      var pixels = bmp.Pixels;

      bool IsTransparent(SKColor color)
      {
        return (color.Red == 0 && color.Green == 0 && color.Blue == 0 && color.Alpha == 0) || 
          (color == SKColors.Transparent);
      }

      Func<int, bool> allWhiteRow = row =>
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
        {
          var px = row * w + i;
          if (!IsTransparent(pixels[px]))
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      };

      Func<int, bool> allWhiteColumn = col =>
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
        {
          var px = col * h + i;
          if (!IsTransparent(pixels[px]))
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      };

      int topmost = 0;
      for (int row = 0; row < h; ++row)
      {
        if (allWhiteRow(row))
          topmost = row;
        else break;
      }

      int bottommost = 0;
      for (int row = h - 1; row >= 0; --row)
      {
        if (allWhiteRow(row))
          bottommost = row;
        else break;
      }

      int leftmost = 0, rightmost = 0;
      for (int col = 0; col < w; ++col)
      {
        if (allWhiteColumn(col))
          leftmost = col;
        else
          break;
      }

      for (int col = w - 1; col >= 0; --col)
      {
        if (allWhiteColumn(col))
          rightmost = col;
        else
          break;
      }

      if (rightmost == 0) rightmost = w; // As reached left
      if (bottommost == 0) bottommost = h; // As reached top.

      int croppedWidth = rightmost - leftmost;
      int croppedHeight = bottommost - topmost;

      if (croppedWidth == 0) // No border on left or right
      {
        leftmost = 0;
        croppedWidth = w;
      }

      if (croppedHeight == 0) // No border on top or bottom
      {
        topmost = 0;
        croppedHeight = h;
      }

      try
      {
        var target = new SKBitmap(croppedWidth, croppedHeight);

        using var canvas = new SKCanvas(target);
        using var img = SKImage.FromBitmap(bmp);
        canvas.DrawImage(img,
          new SKRect(leftmost, topmost, rightmost, bottommost),
          new SKRect(0, 0, croppedWidth, croppedHeight));

        return target;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw new Exception(
          string.Format("Values are topmost={0} btm={1} left={2} right={3} croppedWidth={4} croppedHeight={5}", topmost, bottommost, leftmost, rightmost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
          ex);
      }
    }

  }
}
```