# How to remove empty spaces from PNG images and re-save them

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, image-processing, photoshop

Alright i don't know this is possible programmatically or not with any software but lets learn it.

Now let me demonstrate it with example

i am using paint.net magic wand tolerance 0%

empty space

[image]

and here empty space removed version

[image]

is this possible to do via any software such as c# or photoshop etc

i need to do batch processing

ty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not really know whether this answers your question or not but I hope it does

Here's a code to remove surrounding **white** space from an image from [Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248141/remove-surrounding-whitespace-from-an-image/10392379#10392379)

```
public static Bitmap Crop(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        int w = bmp.Width;
        int h = bmp.Height;

        Func<int, bool> allWhiteRow = row =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
                if (bmp.GetPixel(i, row).R != 255)
                    return false;
            return true;
        };

        Func<int, bool> allWhiteColumn = col =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
                if (bmp.GetPixel(col, i).R != 255)
                    return false;
            return true;
        };

        int topmost = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < h; ++row)
        {
            if (allWhiteRow(row))
                topmost = row;
            else break;
        }

        int bottommost = 0;
        for (int row = h - 1; row >= 0; --row)
        {
            if (allWhiteRow(row))
                bottommost = row;
            else break;
        }

        int leftmost = 0, rightmost = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < w; ++col)
        {
            if (allWhiteColumn(col))
                leftmost = col;
            else
                break;
        }

        for (int col = w - 1; col >= 0; --col)
        {
            if (allWhiteColumn(col))
                rightmost = col;
            else
                break;
        }

        if (rightmost == 0) rightmost = w; // As reached left
        if (bottommost == 0) bottommost = h; // As reached top.

        int croppedWidth = rightmost - leftmost;
        int croppedHeight = bottommost - topmost;

        if (croppedWidth == 0) // No border on left or right
        {
            leftmost = 0;
            croppedWidth = w;
        }

        if (croppedHeight == 0) // No border on top or bottom
        {
            topmost = 0;
            croppedHeight = h;
        }

        try
        {
            var target = new Bitmap(croppedWidth, croppedHeight);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
            {
                g.DrawImage(bmp,
                  new RectangleF(0, 0, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
                  new RectangleF(leftmost, topmost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
                  GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            return target;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(
              string.Format("Values are topmost={0} btm={1} left={2} right={3} croppedWidth={4} croppedHeight={5}", topmost, bottommost, leftmost, rightmost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
              ex);
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

I hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 for quick and good answer. I would change those GetPixels into a LockBit, though.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Not at all. I hope this solves your issue, have a great day :)

Comment: working pretty awesome thanks. though could not make it work as WPF project.

Comment: @ThePoet: change:

    bmp.GetPixel(i, row).R != 255

by

    bmp.GetPixel(i, row).A != 0

and 

    bmp.GetPixel(col, i).R != 255

by

    bmp.GetPixel(col, i).A != 0