# Dynamically change cursor size in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor, cursors, custom-cursor

I created a `.cur` file with a simple cursor filled ellipse inside.

I wish this `Cursor` to act like a "Brush Cursor" meaning that if I change thickness of the brush, the size of the `Cursor` will change (I would also like to change the color of the `Cursor`).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var customCursor = new Cursor(@"CustomCursor.cur");
Mouse.OverrideCursor = currentCursor;
```

Can such thing be done? Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Would this be what you are looking for?  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/cursors-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Not quite. I came across this one, but it doesn't offer any option to dynamically change the size/color of the color during runtime.

Comment: For color you may have to make a few copies of the cursor in different colors and then just change to the one with the color you want. Works well for making buttons highlight on mouse over. Assume it will work the same with the cursor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688159/how-to-override-maximum-32x32-mouse-size-in-windows-like-this-program-can have a look at this. might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this before, and it works.

```
Cursor CreateCursor(double rx, double ry, SolidColorBrush brush, Pen pen)
{
    var vis = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var dc = vis.RenderOpen())
    {
        dc.DrawRectangle(brush, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 0.1), new Rect(0, 0, rx, ry));
        dc.Close();
    }
    var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(64, 64, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    rtb.Render(vis);

    using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var penc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        penc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
        penc.Save(ms1);

        var pngBytes = ms1.ToArray();
        var size = pngBytes.GetLength(0);

        //.cur format spec http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            {//ICONDIR Structure
                ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)0), 0, 2);//Reserved must be zero; 2 bytes
                ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)2), 0, 2);//image type 1 = ico 2 = cur; 2 bytes
                ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)1), 0, 2);//number of images; 2 bytes
            }

            {//ICONDIRENTRY structure
                ms.WriteByte(32); //image width in pixels
                ms.WriteByte(32); //image height in pixels

                ms.WriteByte(0); //Number of Colors in the color palette. Should be 0 if the image doesn't use a color palette
                ms.WriteByte(0); //reserved must be 0

                ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)(rx / 2.0)), 0, 2);//2 bytes. In CUR format: Specifies the horizontal coordinates of the hotspot in number of pixels from the left.
                ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)(ry / 2.0)), 0, 2);//2 bytes. In CUR format: Specifies the vertical coordinates of the hotspot in number of pixels from the top.

                ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(size), 0, 4);//Specifies the size of the image's data in bytes
                ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)22), 0, 4);//Specifies the offset of BMP or PNG data from the beginning of the ICO/CUR file
            }

            ms.Write(pngBytes, 0, size);//write the png data.
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return new Cursor(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to set it, you call:

```
  Mouse.OverrideCursor = CreateCursor(50,50, Brushes.Gold, null);
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/kip9000/4201899

Comment: Very nice, this works really well. I've used this to render SVG images properly scaled to the DPI of the screen. https://github.com/TQLApp/TQL/blob/2d8e2a317bfb341b090bc1161e10eca7317718e2/Tql.App/Support/CursorUtils.cs