# Get actual Image size

Tags: c#

How do I get the USED size of an image. For example:

```
Image image = new Bitmap(400, 400);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
   g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200));
}
```

The image is 400x400 but the used area is 200x200. Is there a way I can get the dimensions of the used area of the image?

Comment: In your example the image has no idea which portion of it was drawn to the graphics context. You'll need to intercept the `FillRectangle` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing out of the box that I'm aware of to do this within the GDI+ libraries.  You could however utilize the concept of whitespace cropping to determine the top/bottom/left/right line of the image that has either perfect whitespace or near ("close" to RGB 255,255,255), and then derive your "used" rectangle from there.

See the following for more details. [Remove surrounding whitespace from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248141/remove-surrounding-whitespace-from-an-image)